# Kinect body orientation detection

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinematics

How can I tell whether a person is facing a Kinect or showing it his/her back?

I am using the Microsoft Kinect SDK v1.7.

Comment: Yeah, it probably won't detect the person that well if at all if their back is turned. It will probably have a bunch of either inferred or not tracked joints in that case. If they are facing the kinect, you can use the Z coordinate of the left/right shoulder to determine if they are facing a certain direction if that is something you would want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Kinect SDK does not track the back of users. It is unable to track a full body rotation, but only a more or less forward facing user.

Now granted, it might get "confused" and be able to track your skeleton when you're facing it with your back, but even then the skeleton will be aligned as if you were facing forward. If it does track you could potentially apply a heuristic that says "are my wrists further from the sensor than my hips?" or "how is the shoulder, elbow, wrist angle oriented", but it would all be inaccurate at best.

Answer (score 0):

When the user stay without any movement it is impossible.But if user is walking the scenario can be solved like this:
Regarding to the [Skeleton Coordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh973078.aspx) in SDK 1.7, the Z coordinates is the distance from the user to the Kinect, So when user walk toward the camera Z is decreased and when user is going far from the camera the Z is increased.
This scenario is only useful when your user is walking normal.